# How to run Intellij project from command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have intellij java project which I run from IDE.
When I run simple java command to run project I get error -
[image: I]

Can any one tell me what is issue here?

Thanks
Nilesh

Comment: You give file names to java, not class names

Answer (score 1):

Please add the .java extension while running the javac command. Something like below:

```
                  javac ..... filename.java
```